# How can I enter JSON value to my postgresql database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

So, I can email address, password and date using this code in node

```
client.query("INSERT INTO manlalaro (emailaddr,pwd,premiumexpiry) values ('tomatopie@coldmail.com','123absurdcodes', DATE '2009-09-19') ",(err,res)=>{
   console.log(err, res)
   client.end()
})
```

But how do I enter JSON data type successfully without getting errors? I have playersaved which is a data type JSON.
[image]

Comment: Postgres have a specific type for JSON. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html

Comment: How are you doing the insert of the JSON data? Which errors are occurring?

Comment: @JDuwe I tried using this code. `
client.query("INSERT INTO manlalaro (emailaddr,pwd,premiumexpiry,playersaved) values ('tomatopie@coldmail.com','123absurdcodes', DATE '2009-09-19', 
{"items":1,"level":7,"description":"Small ax used for harvesting wood."}) ",(err,res)=>{
   console.log(err, res)
   client.end()
})`

Comment: Which errors are occuring?

Comment: Which library are you using to communicate with the DB?
In most cases you can pass the data in a separated parameter like this:
`client.query("INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [1, "text", { "json": "data" }])`. In the example the ? are where the parameters of the array will be inserted, in order.

Comment: Or instead of ? can be $1, $2. Like this: `client.query("INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", [1, "text", { "json": "data" }]);`.

Comment: @Aedric That code is missing escaping of the `"` in the JS string literal. Use `\"`, or concatenate with `JSON.stringify`. And you will need to put the json text in a postgres literal value notation, i.e. `'{…}'` - notice the apostrophes (just like around an ordinary postgres string). But better follow JDuwe's advice and let node-pg do the escaping :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to pass the data to be inserted in a separated parameter where the library or the driver do the right treatment to each data type.

In most cases it will be something like this:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [1, "text", { "json": "data" }]);
```

Or this:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", [1, "text", { "json": "data" }]);
```

The way to know the right thing to do is read the documentation of the library.

If you are using pg (node-postgres) https://node-postgres.com/

Note: As @Aedric pointed out, in some cases your object must be previously "stringified" (JSON.stringify()). But node-postgres claims it do this automatically. (https://node-postgres.com/features/types#uuid%20+%20json%20/%20jsonb).

Comment: thank you so much! I am a bit new to that ($1, $2, $3) thing and I found out it only for node postgresql. Also, the json entry { "json": "data" } should be '{ "json": "data" }'. I think the error is cause by my nest array  ```client.query("INSERT INTO manlalaro (userid,emailaddr,pwd,savegame) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)" , [13,'test1test@coltmail.com','290cgyr789','{"ign":"leroy 

jenkins","level":7,"poisoned status":false}' ] ,(err,res)=>{
   console.log(err, res)
   client.end() })```   
 Thanks again~!

Comment: @Aedric I'm glad it worked. About the json i think it may vary, as the docs says it is automatically converted with JSON.stringify() (https://node-postgres.com/features/types#uuid%20+%20json%20/%20jsonb), but i'll add a note in the answer about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert JSON data in postgresql by converting it into string using `JSON.stringify(Object)`

```
`insert into tableName (id,json_data) values(1,'{"test":1}')`
```

Comment: `var equipment = JSON.stringify(
{"items":1,"level":7,"description":"Small ax used for harvesting wood."})

client.query("INSERT INTO manlalaro (emailaddr,pwd,premiumexpiry,playerSaved) values ('tomatopie@coldmail.com','123absurdcodes', DATE '2009-09-19', equipment) ",

(err,res)=>{
   console.log(err, res)
   client.end()
}) `   It didnt work.

Comment: There is no issue in the JSON data. Can you please show me the error?

Comment: this works for me ```client.query("INSERT INTO manlalaro (userid,emailaddr,pwd,savegame) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)" , [13,'test1test@coltmail.com','290cgyr789','{"ign":"leroy 

jenkins","level":7,"poisoned status":false}' ] ``` no error on this one but I haven't tried using nest array due to SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: This works because this is json stringified. can you show me the query for nested array?

Comment: it turns out I missed a bracket in my first 2 attempts. my third attempt I used this {"ign":"leroy jenkins","level":50,"armor aura":[{"code":31,"dataId":1,"value":0},{"code":22,"dataId":0,"value":-0.1},{"code":33,"dataId":0,"value":-5}], "poisoned status":false} and its fine.